# datepicker for dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript

I have dynamically created textbox in my javascript, the problem is in dynamically created textbox i need to use datepicker  as i am new to javascript

kindly help 
 thanks

```
    row_no4=0;
    var index=1;
     function addRow_otherschsp(tbl4,row5){
    var textbox3a = '<input type=\"text\" size = \"10\" maxlength= \"10\" name=\"othrFA3'+tick+'\" id=\"othrFA3'+tick+'\" placeholder=\"dd/mm/yyyy\"  >';          

    var newRow = tbl4.insertRow(row_no4);   
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.innerHTML = label3;
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
    newCell.innerHTML = "From&nbsp;&nbsp;"+textbox3a+ "To&nbsp;&`enter code here`nbsp;"+ textbox3b;     
    row_no4++;
}
```

Comment: You can try `setTimeout(function() { $('input[name="othrFA3*"]').datepicker(); }, 0);` before closing your above function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function (){
$('body').on('focus',".mydatepickers", function(){
            $(this).datepicker();
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JQUERY

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

[More Details here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ it will be simple

Answer (score 0):

You must download and include the **[jquery datepicker plugin](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)** in your page.

Then, include a class to the dynamically generated text box like this:

```
 function addRow_otherschsp(tbl4,row5){
    var textbox3a = '<input type=\"text\" size = \"10\" maxlength= \"10\" name=\"othrFA3'+tick+'\" id=\"othrFA3'+tick+'\" placeholder=\"dd/mm/yyyy\"  
class=\"mydatepickers\">';          

  .....}
```

Now in your document.ready() add the following code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".mydatepickers" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add necessary jQuery files when working with the datepicker control.

Add all the dependencies of datepicker as mentioned in the [jQuery Datepicker documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

After that wind up your textbox with datepicker method of jQuery like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('input[name="othrFA3*"]').datepicker();
});
```

or else you can add id attribute to your dynamically generated input element

say the id as: datepicker

now your javascript becomes

```
$(function(){
     $(#datepicker').datepicker();
    });
```